# A region is a closed disk centered at origin of certain radius.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, functions

Let $f : X \to \Bbb C$. So $f(X)$ is a region in $\Bbb C$.

Given a region in $\Bbb C$ how can one conclude that it is a closed disk centered at origin of certain radius?

I have shown that origin lies in the region,the region has a upper bound and the fact that the region is symmetric about origin i.e. $f(-z) = f(z)$.

Is it enough or what more we have to show?

Comment: What property $f$ has?

Comment: Can you use Schwarz's lemma, or Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: yes you can use